# Show Multiple location on MapView - NEWBIE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I would like to add more locations on `MapView` something similar to [this image](http://www.leveltendesign.com/files/loopt.PNG). In this image there are only 2 pin points, but i need to have more than 10 locations to add in the map. Is this possible ? and is there any tutorial/sample code where i could start on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the annotation protocol, which simply requires you to include a couple of fields in an object so the map view knows what to annotate the 'pin' with.

You can then add multiple pins to the map view programatically.

I found this blog post useful when I was doing this.

http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

It's called MKPinAnnotationView and you can have as many as you want on map.

You need to implement protocol for it and it has pin as default image property.